# Design Pattern for node.js application and GraphQL API

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, graphql-js

I need to implement Gamification in an R&D squad using GitLab Achievement and its GraphQL API. Which design pattern can I use for this application? This app need to be in node.js, but I can use all module I want.I'm still a student in computer science and I don't want to create a spaghetti-built application for my team.

I understand how to implement gamification, but I'm lost in my code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.